# AWS Secret Manager - how to create a secret that refers another Secret ? - An Alias for a secret?

Tags: alias, aws-secrets-manager

My application uses an existing secret Application/CompanyName/Devl_NUID to access email.
In Other regions there are similar secrets ..../Acpt_NUID, and ..../Prod_NUID.

How can I create an alias that will pull the respective secrets in each of the regions ?

I should not have to change my code or configuration for each of the regions to pull the respect credentials.

I am not able to see any documentation so that I can create a common alias -- say 'myapplication_login' that will pull the set in each region.